# MySQL SELECT from array of ids where one is mandatory

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to know the most efficient SQL query for achieving this problem:

Say we have a table with two columns, one storing entry ids (`entry_id`) and one storing category ids (`cat_id`):

```
 entry_id       cat_id
 3              1
 3              2
 3              3
 3              20
 4              1
 4              2
 4              21
```

I'd like to count how many distinct `entry_id`'s there are in the categories 1, 2 OR 3 but that also must be in `cat_id` 20.

For example, categories 1, 2 and 3 might represent music genres (Country, Pop etc.), while category 20 might be recording formats (CD, Vinyl etc.). So another way of putting it verbally could be: "How many products are there that are on Vinyl and in either the Pop or Country category?"

I could achieve this with a nested loop in code (PHP) or possibly with a nested SQL subquery, but neither feels that efficient. I feel there must be an obvious answer to this staring me in the face...

**EDIT TO ADD:**
I would also like to do this without modifying the database design, as it's a third party system.

**FURTHER EXAMPLE TO CLARIFY:**
Another real-world example of why I'd need this data:

Let's say the category ids instead represent either:

- Accommodation Types (Camping = 20, Holiday Cottage = 21)

OR

- Continents and their sub-regions (i.e. Europe = 1, UK = 2, England = 3)

Let's say someone has selected that they are interested in camping (`cat_id` = 1). Now we need to count how many camping products there are in the Europe. A product might be tagged as both Europe (parent), UK (child) AND England (grand-child), giving us an array of category ids 1, 2 or 3. So we now need to count how many distinct products there are in both those categories AND the original accommodation category of 1 (camping).

So having selected Camping, the end result might look something like:

- Europe: 4 camping products

  - UK: 2 camping products

    - England : 1 camping product
    - Wales : 1 camping product
  - France: 2 camping products 
    etc.

Hope that helps...

Comment: considered adding a `format` column?

Comment: It's a good idea, but I need to do this without modifying the table structure. Sorry, I should have included this in the OP. I've added this info now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want GROUP BY, COUNT() and EXISTS()

```
declare @t table(entry_id int, cat_id int)

insert @t select 1, 1
insert @t select 2, 1
insert @t select 1, 2
insert @t select 2, 2
insert @t select 3, 1
insert @t select 1, 20

select t1.cat_id, COUNT(*)
from @t as t1
where exists(
    select * from @t
    where t1.entry_id = entry_id 
    and cat_id = 20)
group by t1.cat_id
```

V2 using join instead of EXISTS()

```
declare @t table(entry_id int, cat_id int)

insert @t select 1, 1
insert @t select 2, 1
insert @t select 1, 2
insert @t select 2, 2
insert @t select 3, 1
insert @t select 1, 20

select t1.cat_id, COUNT(*)
from @t as t1
join @t as t2 on t1.entry_id = t2.entry_id and t2.cat_id = 20
group by t1.cat_id
```

Comment: Thank you. Would this not just give the total number of entries in each category though? I need to specifically constrain the COUNT on two sets of input category ids. I'm interested to know if your solution could be expanded to do this though... hmm.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct entry_id) from myTable where cat_id=20 and entry_id in 
(select distinct entry_id from myTable where cat_id in (1,2,3));
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, many thanks. Still interested to see if there is any way of doing it without a subquery though, but it's not the end of the world if I do need to use one I guess.

Answer (score 1):

With no subqueries, using `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

Join the table to itself using entry_id (this gives you all possible pairs of cat_id for that entry_id).  Select rows having cat_id both a member of (1,2,3) and the second cat_id = 20.

```
SELECT r1.entry_id
FROM records r1
JOIN records r2  USING(entry_id)
WHERE r1.cat_id IN (1,2,3)
  AND r2.cat_id = 20 GROUP BY entry_id;
```